# Why I could not import pptx package in Python 3.5

Tags: python

I managed to  install python-pptx 0.6.5 using 'pip install python-pptx', but when I "from pptx import Presentation", it reported errors. Can anyone kindly help me out? Error report is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Course_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pptx import Presentation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pptx/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pptx.api import Presentation  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pptx/api.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .package import Package
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pptx/package.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .opc.package import OpcPackage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pptx/opc/package.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .oxml import CT_Relationships, serialize_part_xml
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pptx/opc/oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it the other way around: `from pptx import Presentation`

Comment: That's not the problem. It was just a typo in the question. The stack trace would be completely different if the code had really be that.